# propagation of uncertainties of squared variables

Tags: error-propagation

One rule of the propagation of uncertainties goes like this:

If $Q=A.B$ then $σ_Q=|A.B| √((σ_A/A)^2+(σ_B/B)^2 )$

so if $Q=A^2=A.A$ then $σ_Q=A^2.√(2.(σ_A/A)^2 )=|A.σ_A.√2|$.

However, another rule is:
If $Q = A^b$ then $σ_Q=|b.A^(b-1).σ_A |$

so if $b = 2$ then $σ_Q=|A.σ_A.2|$.
Which one is right?

Answer (score 2):

If $Q=A.B$, you get what you said. But if $Q=A^2=A.A$, the answer is not simply the same as substituting $B=A$ (check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Simplification)).
What happens here is that, when B=A, then the 'independent variables hypothesis' is not valid anymore, and your answer is wrong.

Particularly, I prefer the general formula (applied to your problem) 
$$ \sigma_Q^2 = \left( \frac{\partial Q}{\partial A} \right)^2 \sigma_A^2$$ 
which gives as answer $ \sigma_Q = |2.A.\sigma_A|$

Comment: Yes, its the independence of the variables that is the difference. Thanks.